# Sorting info from rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue where, when I add 2 cases in the query, the result I expect isn't what I need.

```
     SELECT BranchId
      ,i.[ItemId]      
      ,i.[PartStatus]
      ,i.[ItemName1]
      ,i.[ItemName2]
      ,i.[Length]
      ,i.[Width]
      ,i.[Height]
      ,i.[Onlineshop]
      ,(case when BranchId = '1080' and StockLocationId = '800' then mist.CutFlag end) as cutflag800
      ,(case when branchid = '1081' and StockLocationId = '810' then mist.CutFlag end) as Cutflag810
  FROM [dwh01].[live].[DimItem] i
       left join live.Map_Item_StockLocation mist
             on i.ItemKey = mist.ItemKey
       inner join live.DimStockLocation stl
             on stl.[StockLocationKey] = mist.[StockLocationKey]
        where BranchId in('1080','1081') and StockLocationId in('800','810')
       and i.PartStatus = 'A'
order by ItemId
```

The result is 2 rows for itemid and I need 1 row itemid and 2 columns cutflag for stock locations 800 and 810.

[image: cutflag]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? I see no aggregate functions.

Comment: The square-bracket delimiters indicate this is Microsoft SQL Server, so I changed the tag. MySQL is not Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Please **don't** use images for data, code or errors. Use formatted/tabular text.

Comment: Im using MSSql, i removed the group by, was testing another func and the result is same without group by anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want reduce the rows you could try using ( fake ) aggregation functions a min() or max() for eliminate the null values in cutflag cols

```
    SELECT 
           i.[ItemId]      
          ,i.[PartStatus]
          ,i.[ItemName1]
          ,i.[ItemName2]
          ,i.[Length]
          ,i.[Width]
          ,i.[Height]
          ,i.[Onlineshop]
          ,MIN(case when BranchId = '1080' and StockLocationId = '800' then mist.CutFlag end) as cutflag800
          ,MIN(case when branchid = '1081' and StockLocationId = '810' then mist.CutFlag end) as Cutflag810
      FROM [dwh01].[live].[DimItem] i
           inner join live.Map_Item_StockLocation mist
                 on i.ItemKey = mist.ItemKey
           inner join live.DimStockLocation stl
                 on stl.[StockLocationKey] = mist.[StockLocationKey]
           where StockLocationId in('800','810')
           and i.PartStatus = 'A'
    group by 
     StockLocationId,
     ItemId,
     PartStatus,
     ItemName1,
     ItemName2,
     width,
     Length,
     Height,
     Onlineshop
    order by ItemId
```

Comment: result is the same.

Comment: asnwer  updated  .. removed  cutFlag from group by   ..

Comment: Nope, the result doesnt change at all

Comment: @svetozarslavkov  based  on your image  ..  the new code without cutFlag should work ..  check better and eventually provide a clear data sample, ..

Comment: I added branchid, because there are 2 branched 1080 and 1081 and i guess the second row that appears is for the second branch. And when i added it my guess was correct. So now the question is how  to display the cutflag in 2 columns for stock locations 800 and 810 without the branchid messing the result.

Comment: asnswer  updated ..  with ggregation applied  to the new case

Comment: I tried that and it just doesnt work like expected...

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my query using window function instead of group by. Please check:

```
  SELECT 
           i.[ItemId]      
          ,i.[PartStatus]
          ,i.[ItemName1]
          ,i.[ItemName2]
          ,i.[Length]
          ,i.[Width]
          ,i.[Height]
          ,i.[Onlineshop]
          ,max(case when stocklocationid = '800' then mist.CutFlag end)
OVER (PARTITION BY i.ITEMID) as cutflag800
          ,max(case when stocklocationid = '810' then mist.CutFlag end) OVER (PARTITION BY i.ITEMID) as Cutflag810
      FROM [dwh01].[live].[DimItem] i
           inner join live.Map_Item_StockLocation mist
                 on i.ItemKey = mist.ItemKey
           inner join live.DimStockLocation stl
                 on stl.[StockLocationKey] = mist.[StockLocationKey]
           where StockLocationId in('800','810')
           and i.PartStatus = 'A'
    
    order by ItemId
```

This will select max(cutflag) group by itemid only. all the other columns will be ignored while finding max().

Comment: Nope, still same. The itemid stays on 2 rows and doesnt go into one while the cutflag also goes for stock location 800 in first row and 810 second row. I guess maybe there is another column that has 2 values and is dividing the result for 1 item id in 2 rows.. Idk im trying to find a solution and nothing works.

Comment: I have revised my answer to adopt newly risen condition.

Comment: Hi, yeah that worked, still there are 2 rows item id,but afterwards the excel remove duplicated made a decent table with exactly what i need. Thanks!

Comment: That's great to know. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "inner join live.Map_Item_StockLocation mist" to  "***left*** join live.Map_Item_StockLocation mist"